# Can't load JIntellitype while running SikuliX

Tags: java, sikuli, jintellitype

I've been suffering with this issue all day long, I've tried looking for solutions throughout the webs, found some people that had the same issue but trying to solve the way they did, but it didn't work for me.

Debug log:

> runsikulix.cmd -d 3

```
+++ running this Java
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
+++ trying to run SikuliX
+++ using: -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsikuli.FromCommandLine -jar C:\Users\GGARCIA\Desktop\Sikulix\sikulix.jar -d 3
[debug] RunTimeINIT: loadOptions: check: C:\Users\GGARCIA\Desktop\Sikulix
[debug] RunTimeINIT: loadOptions: check: C:\Users\GGARCIA
[debug] RunTimeINIT: loadOptions: check: C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixStore
[debug] RunTimeINIT: global init: entering as: IDE
[debug] RunTimeINIT: ScreenDevice 0 has (0,0) --- will be primary Screen(0)
[debug] RunTimeINIT: Monitor 0: (0, 0) 1920 x 1080
[debug] RunTimeINIT: runs as sikulix.jar in: C:\Users\GGARCIA\Desktop\Sikulix
[debug] RunTimeINIT: exists libs folder at: C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201612100100
[debug] RunTimeINIT: addToWindowsSystemPath: added to systempath:
C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201612100100
[debug] RunTimeINIT: checkJavaUsrPath: added to ClassLoader.usrPaths
***** show environment for IDE (build 201612100100)
user.home: C:\Users\GGARCIA
user.dir (work dir): C:\Users\GGARCIA\Desktop\Sikulix
user.name: GGARCIA
java.io.tmpdir: C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Local\Temp
running 64Bit on Windows (10.0) from a jar
java 8-64 version 1.8.0_111-b14 vm 25.111-b14 class 52.0 arch amd64
app data folder: C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix
libs folder: C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201612100100
executing jar: C:\Users\GGARCIA\Desktop\Sikulix\sikulix.jar
*** classpath dump sikulix
  0: /C:/Users/GGARCIA/Desktop/Sikulix/sikulix.jar
*** classpath dump end
***** show environment end
[debug] RunTimeIDE: global init: leaving
[debug] RunTimeIDE: initIDEbefore: entering
[debug] RunTimeIDE: initIDEbefore: leaving
[debug] RunTimeIDE: initAPI: entering
[debug] RunTimeIDE: resourceList: enter
[debug] RunTimeIDE: resourceLocation: (class org.sikuli.ide.SikuliIDE) /Lib/sikuli
[debug] RunTimeIDE: resourceList: having jar: jar:file:/C:/Users/GGARCIA/Desktop/Sikulix/sikulix.jar!/Lib/sikuli
[debug] RunTimeIDE: files exported: 7 from: Lib/sikuli to:
 C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\sikuli
[debug] RunTimeIDE: initAPI: leaving
[debug] init user preferences
[debug] IDE: running with Locale: pt_BR
[debug] --- Sikuli parameters ---
[debug] 1: -d
[debug] 2: 3
[info] HotkeyManager: add Capture Hotkey: CTRL+SHIFT 2 (50, 3)
[debug] HotkeyManager: add Capture Hotkey: CTRL+SHIFT 2 (50, 3)
[error] WindowsHotkeyManager: JIntellitype problem: Could not load JIntellitype.dll from local file system or from inside JAR
[debug] RunTimeIDE: final cleanup
[debug] FileManager: deleteFileOrFolder:
C:\Users\GGARCIA\AppData\Local\Temp\Sikulix_1659037070
```

- Currently OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Currently Sikulix Version: Nightly Build
  sikulixsetup-1.1.1-20161210.001637-82

I've tried:

- Different builds (nightly builds, latest release 1.1.0)
- Tried downloading the DLL from https://code.google.com/archive/p/jintellitype/downloads and putting
  it in:

  - SikuliX Folder
  - Windows System32 folder
  - Inside the JAR file (using winrar)
- Also tried download the DLL available in the GitHub project's page.
- Tried updating my java to the latest version, both Java JDK and JRE. Both 64bit and 32bit.
- Executing only sikulix.jar:

  - Opening as windows default choice)
  - Open-with (open with java)
  - Using java -jar sikulix.jar.

None of those above worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the version of java you're running is not aligned with your SikuliX install.

Make a note of the Java version used when you did your install, you can look in the install log for `RunSetup: RunningJava:`.  Make sure that when you initiate `runsikulix.cmd`, it has that same version.

I suspect that the install was with a later version and perhaps a 64 bit version, and when you attempt to run SikuliX, it picks up an older verions, perhaps a 32 bit version.

The reason is that the `runsikulix.cmd` gives weight to the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.  Since running Java on the command line (as you probably did when you installed) does not use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, You should be able to remove it (although there is the possiblity that other programs do need it).  Alternatively, you could alter `runsikulix.cmd` so that it ignores the environment variable.  In other words, you could hard-code your Java location.

To alter environment variables on Windows 10, see [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).